# How can I know when a user has closed a Google Drive Editor session?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I could poll the [changes api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list), but I would never know when to stop polling it. I'm currently relying on polling the javascript popup window's closed property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible with the Drive SDK. The Drive SDK, and the Drive editors are both individual clients on the same data, and are not really connected like this.

Sorry.